# Альтернатива alert в JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно выводить текст на экран не во всплывающем окне, а именно в виде текста, как, например echo в PHP или < p >Текст< /p > в HTML. Кто знает решение?

Comment: `console.log` и f12 пробовали?

Comment: @Darth причем тут консоль? Человеку же в HTML вставить надо...

Comment: @AGS17 Почему вы так решили? echo в PHP это совершенно не обязательно про HTML..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так?

```js
$("#target").html("<p>Hello, World!</p>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Вся суть добавления сообщения на страницу заключается в поиске нужного элемента и редактировании его содержания. Для поиска (вариант сверху) использовался jQuery и селектор требуемого элемента ([основы jQuery](https://habrahabr.ru/post/38526/)).

Или без jQuery:

```js
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = "<p>Hello, World!</p>";
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Попробуй писать более развернутые ответы. Если используешь какую-то библиотеку, стоит добавить какую, раз про нее нет ничего в вопросе

Comment: function loadTime() {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'time.php', false);
          xhr.send();
          alert(xhr.responseText);
      } - вот какой у меня щас код. в time.php всего 1 строчка: echo 5 (выводит просто 5 на экран, как обычный текст(параграф)). только нужно вместо всплывающего окна выводить текст по-обычному

Comment: Ну так и замените ваш `alert(xhr.responseText);` на `document.getElementById('ELEMENT_ID').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;`, где `ELEMENT_ID` - id элемента, в который вы хотите вставить ваш текст (`target` в моем примере).

Comment: В примере можно опустить `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",` так как сниппет вставляет код js перед закрывающим тегом body, поэтому к моменту его выполнения, все элементы уже доступны

Comment: @Grundy благодарю за инфу, подравил.